# Is the whole of reality what is being denied by some Buddhists?

Tags: death, reality, existence

1. Is the whole of reality what is being denied by some Buddhists?

So, for as long as the sensation of pleasure or an atom or visual consciousness or apple is thought to belong to everything that exists, we are confused about them; and everyone is. If so:

2. can we add that everything absent from the whole of reality exists?

I know you can literally couple the fire sermon (the Buddha goes nowhere after death) with the unanswered questions (does the Buddha exist after death, in unanswerable). But maybe they're saying that in his no longer existing in the world, he is beyond every concept except existence? So the question is unanswerable because of the assumption that he has somewhere to go.

Comment: noumenon does exist as something in addition to phenomena, but not ***all*** phenomena?

Comment: The statement in the 3rd paragraph -- "Anything which exists" etc. -- what (reference)  is that based on? Or what are you trying to say there and how is it connected to the (title of the) question?

Comment: I'll explain sorry @ChrisW

Comment: The whole first question would be clearer with a reference -- could you quote or link to what you're asking about? I mean, the first question is, "Some Buddhists are denying something -- is that 'something' the whole of reality?" ... but you don't specify which Buddhists you're asking about, nor what they said or wrote, nor even which school of Buddhism, so I think it's hard to be sure of what you're asking about.

Comment: all of them @ChrisW do you have a favourite I can namecheck (lol)?

Comment: The question seems to suppose or presuppose that Buddhists believe that, "Anything which exists, exists outside the whole (of 'reality', not 'the entire apple')." But I'm finding it hard to make sense of that assertion, i.e. to relate it to any Buddhist doctrine that I know of.

Comment: ah dwai @ChrisW I'd delete but unfortunately am unable to

Answer (score 2):

If you pick up a bowl of water and carry it across the room to a table, the water will splash against the sides of the bowl and develop eddies and waves  as you move. If you come back an hour later, The splashing and eddies and waves are gone. So where did they go?

When pure consciousness is disturbed it develops its own splashes and eddies and wavs. Some of these we alienate as 'karma' or 'phenomena'; others we identify with as 'self'. If we don't let them still, they perpetuate, constantly recreating themselves. If we do still them they fade to nothing, and yet we lose nothing in the fading.

A man we call Gautama awakened to the stillness of pure consciousness. The man died; the stillness didn't.

Comment: The question only made sense to me after I read your answer. Thank you. :D

Answer (score 0):

Even brain-mastubating can be taken on as if it would be real, right?

Why not simply take on ways of thinking the Liberal pointed out to go beyond desire of all kind?

In that way, of which he tries, good householder wouln't stop go after the refrigerator or are there first signs?

Comment: I like puzzles. I guess it's sad no-one else likes mine, but whatever.

Comment: it's not like every one of my questions are the same (or even that any of them are sufficiently answered). They may spring from the same motivation, broadly speaking, but again: whatever

Comment: brainmastubating. Or public farting. Right?

Comment: what are you doing, shitting in my mouth?

Comment: @user22169 On this site, if you're going to post an answer, then you should usually try to [answer the question](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/61/254) without saying "that's the wrong question to be asking". If you don't want to answer then don't, but maybe usually try and do it without appearing to criticize the user for asking.

Comment: What does the TOS say on "that's not the answer" in comments, criticize answers? How does on appear to "criticize" a user for answering? Thoughts, links?